# Sharepoint C# Data Transfer Date Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, csom, date-time

I transfer data from one tenant list to another tenant list with c#. I'm passing the date columns into a string value.

Received data; 3/1/2023 18:00
String value; 3/1/2023 18:00
Value written to the new list; 1/3/2023 18:00

Date format in two lists: DD/MM/YYYY
However, the places of the month and day change while writing data. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you check and make sure both SharePoint sites are having same regional and language settings? Let me know if this works.

Comment: The regional settings of both sharepoint sites are the same. I even have the same problem when transferring from a list to a list in the same sharepoint. The order of the day and month changes.

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: I fixed the problem when I made the variable datetime. But I still couldn't understand why there is a change of place when I assign a string value.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.